# How should I go about overriding or switching between an internal control voltage source when an external source gets connected?

Tags: analog, audio, control, switching, synthesizer

For example, I'm using a potentiometer to modulate an internally generated +5v audio signal, and I'm sending the output signal down to the next part of my circuit. If I were to add an external input to the circuit, how could I make sure the circuit completely ignores the potentiometer output and instead feeds from the external voltage input?

I thought of maybe isolating the ground on the external input and using a comparator and some transistors to switch inputs if the voltage to ground on the input changes (indicating a live connector is plugged in). That solution seems very unreliable and complicated to me, though. Am I on the right track, or is there an easier solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest thing here is to use a jack specifically designed for this purpose.  If you use a 3.5mm plug on the external cable, you can buy a 3.5mm jack that will short your internal (potentiometer) signal to the tip input until the plug is inserted.  The displacement of the plug breaks the internal connection and uses the external one instead.
[image: Jack with switch]
Thanks to [CUI devices](https://www.cuidevices.com/) for the image.

If you want an electronic solution, you'll have to tell us more about the characteristics of your external input

Comment: I wasn't ware they made jacks like that! That's so much simpler than what I thought of doing.

I don't think an electronic solution will be necessary for this. It would probably be a lot more complex and expensive. 

Thanks for the help!

Comment: It depends if you want to switch mono or stereo with one plug how it is implemented.  Mono can use the contacts as SPDT. STEREO would use it as a logic signal to disable the wired OR internal stereo amplifier.